# Is my way in solve the linear congruence problem $15x \equiv 31 \pmod{47}$ correct?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences

$15x \equiv 31 \pmod{47}$

---

\begin{align*}
47 & = 15 \cdot 3 + 1\\
15 & = 2 \cdot 7 + 1\\
1 & = 15 - 7 \cdot 2\\
1 & = 15 - 7 \cdot [47 + (-3) \cdot 15]\\
1 & = (-7)(47) + (22)(15)
\end{align*}
Now the inverse of $15 \equiv 31 \pmod{47}$ is $22$.
$x$ is simply $22 \cdot 31$ which is $682$. 
$x = 682$.
Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, I think you are  correct. The answer is also right, but you should bring $x$ under $47$ (by taking the remainder after division by $47$) to get a better looking answer. That would give you $x = 24$.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: The first line of the displayed equation is wrong.